# Sharepoint: Metadata Word Cloud

Tags: metadata, sharepoint-online

Is there a way of displaying the Metadata from a SharePoint Online Library, as a Word Cloud?

I came upon this: https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/09/3d-tag-cloud-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/ but could not manage to make it work.